# How can I create a measure that can dynamically change according to a slicer selection in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

How can I create a measure in Power BI that can dynamically change according to a slicer selection?

i.e. I have 4 donut charts (shown in the attached picture below) for showing the number of user stories in the Second last iteration, last iteration, current iteration, and next iteration respectively. I need to change the info shown on the donut charts to include the same information but with respect to the selected iteration on the iteration path slicer (meaning that whenever I change the iteration path in the slicer, it gets me the info on the 4 donut charts for the second last iteration, last iteration, current selected iteration, and the following iteration to the one selected). How can I do that?

Thank you so much in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iirb.jpg

Comment: It's a standard problem, but don't show the donut charts - show us the data model instead. Power BI is not PowerPoint. Nobody can do anything with the donut charts!

Answer (score 0):

From which parameter you want to add slicer ?

Ex: if you want to change charts according to slicr date range select you can try below scenario,

- Define global calendar.
- Add date column to each table .
- From here drag and drop your tables date columns to calendar column ,
  to make relationship.
- Then add calendar column to slicer.

Comment: The column I am using to set the slicer is "Iteration path" something like in the attached snapshot below. I want to show the number of User Stories at each selected iteration path, with the "State" on the legend, doing so from counting the "Work Item Id" which is in the same table. How can I make this kind of measure, depending on the selected iteration path number from the slicer? 

https://imgur.com/a/7n9D2lN